# Pandas - merging Interval Index to float

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, intervals

I am using qcut to get bins of prediction values and calculating the standard error for each bin.  I then want to apply these standard errors to predictions in another dataframe by mapping that dataframe's predictions to the SEs by bin that I made.

Below is the code I am using, with the last line made up.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 2)), columns=['Pred','Error'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(1000, 2)), columns=['Pred'])
df['binned']=pd.qcut(df['Pred'], 10)    
binSEs=df.groupby(['binned'],observed=False)['Error'].std()  

**df2['binSE']=unknownintervaljoin(df['Pred'],binSEs)**
```

Alternatively if I could make a 'binned' column in df2 based on binSEs, I could merge on the binSEs series.

Comment: I think `df['binSE'] = df["binned"].map(binSEs)` might be what you want. But you could also get it directly via `df.groupby(['binned'],observed=False)['Error'].transform("std")`

Comment: but how do I make the binSE column in df2, which only has the Pred variable? @Chrysophylaxs

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want... Maybe: `pd.cut(df2["Pred"], pd.IntervalIndex(binSEs.index)).map(binSEs)`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by first calculating the binned column in `df2` based on the values in `df['Pred']`, and then merging on the 'binned' column with `binSEs` :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 2)), columns=['Pred', 'Error'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 1)), columns=['Pred'])

# Calculate the 'binned' column in df2
df2['binned'] = pd.qcut(df2['Pred'], 10, labels=False, duplicates='drop')

# Calculate binSEs
df['binned'] = pd.qcut(df['Pred'], 10)
binSEs = df.groupby(['binned'], observed=False)['Error'].std()

# Merge df2 with binSEs based on the 'binned' column
df2['binSE'] = df2['binned'].map(binSEs)

print(df2.head())
```

In this code, we first calculate the 'binned' column in `df2` using `pd.qcut`. Then, we merge `df2` with `binSEs` based on the 'binned' column, ensuring that the mapping is performed correctly. Finally, we rename the 'Error' column to 'binSE' in the resulting `df2` dataframe.

This should give you `df2` with the 'binSE' column containing the standard errors based on the bins from `df`.